# Tranform Data Using Map Operator in RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I have one third Party API which returns data as below -
It has been called from Angular Service using `HttpClient.`

```
const someObject = {

    employees:[   

        {name:"XYZ",age:30},
        {name:"ABC",age:28},
    ]
}
```

I want to transform this data into below structure where 
**name, age** are as it is and **description will be calculated based on name and age**

```
{ 
  name : 
  age  : 
  description: //calculate based on name and age 
},
{ 
  name : 
  age  : 
  description:  //calculate based on name and age 
}
```

Above structure will be typed to some `Interface` and this is ultimately returned from my `Angular service`

How can I do this using `RxJS` ?

Can anybody please help me as I am struggling with it

Ultimately , my Angular service will return data as above structure ?

**EDIT :**

Based on responses got , I tried below :

```
return this.http.get<any>(url).pipe(
            map(data => data.employees),
            map(employees =>{
              values.map(employee =>{
                console.log('individual value =',employee);
                return{
                  employee,
                  description:employee.name + "" + employee.age 
                }
              })          
            })
        )
```

But when this Observable is subscribed , I am getting value as `undefined`.

Is it because the second map operator `map(employees` is not returning anything ? 
How can I make it return object constructed from **inner map** ?

Comment: Have you tried using `pipe` and then `map` operator to create new object containing description along with other fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so basically you want to add and process additional property:

assume this is the method in your service:

```
getData(){...}
```

Then you can simply do that:

```
const employees$ = this.service.getData().pipe(
  map(data => data.employees),
  map(employees => employees.map(employee => {
       const description = `My name is ${employee.name}`;
       return {...employee, description};
    }
  )
);
```

then in `employees$` you have the observable with employees with the structure you want

Comment: seems it will  {...employee, description}; not work

Comment: In addition there is one more problem . I have edited the question . Can you take a look ?

Comment: yea - there should be return added:

Comment: return values.map(employee =>{

Answer (score 1):

```js
    const someObject = {
    
        employees:[   
            {name:"XYZ",age:30},
            {name:"ABC",age:28},
        ]
    }
    
    
    let description = 'description goes here';
    let result = someObject.employees.map( o => { return  {...o, ...{description} } });
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
of([
        {name:"XYZ",age:30},
        {name:"ABC",age:28},
    ]).pipe(
    map(employees => 
      employees.map(
        elem => {return {
          "name": elem.name,
          "age": elem.age,
          "description": 'blablabla'
        }}
      )
    )
  ).subscribe(employees => console.log(employees))
```

Now just change the string in the description.
Hope I helped